# GUI interfaces for computationally heavy programs

Tags: java, r, matlab, user-interface, mle

I'm exploring options for the best way to achieve the following. I have a computationally heavy model built in R (it uses MLE at its core) and I'd like to provide a front end GUI to use this model. The input to the model is especially simple, just two lists of numbers, and the model spits out various parameters. Essentially, the GUI component will be a single window that the user can upload a file, fill in a few text boxes, and indicate some preferences (e.g., maybe a checkbox or two).

I know Java well and my first thought was to somehow link up a Java GUI with the R code, via console or some other method.

I've compiled a list of options I thought of, but know very little about. What do you think would be most feasible and/or easiest for achieving this? Here were my ideas

- include actual R code within Java (not sure if this is possible)
- include actual Java GUI code within R (not sure if this is possible)
- implement the actual MLE model in Java (really don't want to do this, as the R code works great and I love the parameters it spits back out to me, such as liklihoods and confidence intervals)
- rewrite the MLE model in Matlab, and include Java GUI code within Matlab
- use native R GUI (does this even exist), and then make an R executable of some type

The overarching goal is to let the user run this complex R code via a nice GUI window such that they don't need to tweak parameters at the top of the R file (e.g., file paths).

Comment: _include actual R code within Java_ ***(not sure if this is possible)*** [JRI](http://rforge.net/JRI/) :)

Comment: When you say MLE do you mean Maximum Likelihood Estimate

Comment: [RCaller](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Frcaller.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Frcaller.pdf&ei=NivpUtTiCqbyyAHTkoCoBw&usg=AFQjCNE3aoQtT_GlGuEonIH7xatWNy7twQ&sig2=EwBK2FiTJ0OSP_uco2IhiA)?

Comment: Yes, Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Comment: I appreciate the links to the various R/Java packages. I'm moreso wondering what you think would be the easiest option given what I want to do. It doesn't necessarily HAVE TO BE R/Java combination.

Comment: "make an R executable of some type" is another can of worms, by the way...

Answer (score 4):

Or you could do everything in R with [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/).

For some examples see [their demos](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/showcase/).

You might also be interested in this [example interface](http://vnijs.rady.ucsd.edu:3838/marketing/).

Comment: R with shiny looks great. I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you go to [www.r-project.org](http://www.r-project.org) and in the left column near the bottom is a link "Related Projects".  After following that link there is a section on "R GUIs" that has a lot of information on existing GUIs and tools for creating your own GUI for R code with pro's and con's for the various tools.

Comment: Eventual link destination is http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/ and there's packages for widget toolkits Tk and Gtk if you want to build a native app and not a browser interface.

Comment: Just curious but ... why would you prefer a 'native app' over a browser interface at this point. If you want your app to work cross-platform it would be hard to beat a browser.

Comment: [Deducer](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.DeducerManual) is Java based and might be of specific interest to OP.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Rattle: A Graphical User Interface for Data Mining using R](http://rattle.togaware.com/) which looks impressive. I have not tried out myself yet, but maybe worth exploring.

[image: Rattle screenshot]

Comment: My impression was that Rattle is a (very nice) GUI, not a toolbox to build a GUI.